# Python: keep apostrophe with verbs

Tags: python, tokenize

I would like to tokenize a list of sentence, but keep negated verbs as unique words.

```
t = """As aren't good. Bs are good"""
print(word_tokenize(t))
['As', 'are', "n't", 'good', '.', 'Bs', 'are', 'good']
```

I would like to have "aren't" and "are" separate. With word_tokenize I get "n't". Same for other negated forms like (Couldn't, didn't, et).

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract individual words from a space-separated sentence, use Python's `split()` method.

```
t = "As aren't good. Bs are good"
print (t.split())
['As', "aren't", 'good.', 'Bs', 'are', 'good']
```

You can specify other delimiters in the `split()` method as well. For example, if you wanted to tokenize your string based on a full-stop, you could do something like this:

```
print (t.split("."))
["As aren't good", ' Bs are good']
```

Read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 0):

use split of re module.https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
import re
t = "As aren't good. Bs are good"
list(filter(None,re.split(r"[\s+.]",t)))
```

output:

```
['As', "aren't", 'good', 'Bs', 'are', 'good']
```